# PHP RecursiveIteratorIterator - Reverse and Count results

Tags: php, object, count, reverse

I have the following:

```
<?php

$path = '/home/user/test';

$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $path  );
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dir );
$dir_iterator = new RegexIterator( $iterator, '/^.+\.php/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH );

?>
```

So far so good, but I need to **reverse the results**, to archive the same effect as array_reverse()

I tried like this, with no success:

```
<?php

$dir_iterator = array_reverse( (array)$dir_iterator );

?>
```

Also, how can I get the **number of results returned**? I tried this, but isn't working:

```
<?php

$total_results = count( $dir_iterator );

?>
```

Can anybody help me out?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is `iterator_to_array` you can try

```
$dir_iterator =  array_reverse(iterator_to_array($dir_iterator ));
```

To count Iterators what you need is :

```
$total_results = iterator_count( $dir_iterator );
```

Better Sill Implement Yours

```
$dir_iterator = new ReverseIterator($dir_iterator);

foreach ( $dir_iterator as $file ) {
    // do your thing
}

// To get total
echo count($dir_iterator);
```

Class Used

```
class ReverseIterator extends ArrayIterator implements Countable {
    private $t;

    public function __construct(Iterator $it) {
        $r = array_reverse(iterator_to_array($it));
        $this->t = count($r);
        parent::__construct($r);
        unset($r);
    }

    function count() {
        return $this->t;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome  .. see updated code for re-usable code you can use